# validation of python script for extracting values based on regex

Tags: python, regex

I have data of the form:

```
submission #,scores
882,"Overall evaluation: 1
Invite to interview: 1
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 3
Use or provision of open data (1): 3
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 4
""Open by default"" (2): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 1
Market opportunity and timing (1): 3
Market opportunity and timing (2): 1
Triple bottom line impact (1): 2
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 1
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 1
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 1
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
882,"Overall evaluation: 2
Invite to interview: 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 1
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 4
Use or provision of open data (1): 4
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 4
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 4
Market opportunity and timing (1): 4
Market opportunity and timing (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (1): 4
Triple bottom line impact (2): 1
Triple bottom line impact (3): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 3
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
883,"Overall evaluation: 1
Invite to interview: 1
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 4
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 3
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 4
Use or provision of open data (1): 2
Use or provision of open data (2): 3
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 3
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 1
Market opportunity and timing (1): 3
Market opportunity and timing (2): 1
Triple bottom line impact (1): 1
Triple bottom line impact (2): 4
Triple bottom line impact (3): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 3
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 1
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 4
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
883,"Overall evaluation: 1
Invite to interview: 1
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 1
Use or provision of open data (1): 2
Use or provision of open data (2): 1
""Open by default"" (1): 3
""Open by default"" (2): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 2
Market opportunity and timing (1): 2
Market opportunity and timing (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (1): 1
Triple bottom line impact (2): 2
Triple bottom line impact (3): 2
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 3
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
885,"Overall evaluation: 2
Invite to interview: 1
Strength or novelty of the idea (1): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (2): 2
Strength or novelty of the idea (3): 2
Use or provision of open data (1): 2
Use or provision of open data (2): 2
""Open by default"" (1): 2
""Open by default"" (2): 2
Value proposition and potential scale (1): 1
Value proposition and potential scale (2): 2
Market opportunity and timing (1): 2
Market opportunity and timing (2): 1
Triple bottom line impact (1): 2
Triple bottom line impact (2): 1
Triple bottom line impact (3): 1
Knowledge and skills of the team (1): 4
Knowledge and skills of the team (2): 2
Capacity to realise the idea (1): 1
Capacity to realise the idea (2): 3
Capacity to realise the idea (3): 2
Appropriateness of the budget to realise the idea: 3"
```

and the following python script:

```
map = {}
lines=open("new_data.csv",'r').read().splitlines()
for l in lines:
    data = l.split('"Overall evaluation:')
    if len(data) == 2:
        if data[0] not in map.keys():
            map[data[0]] = (0,0)
        map[data[0]] = (map[data[0]][0]+int(data[1]) , map[data[0]][1]+1)
for x, y in map.items():
    print(str(x) + ", " + str(y[0]/y[1]))
```

what I think is happening is that it takes the average of the two `Overall evaluation:` numbers and outputs it next to the submission number, is that correct?

Comment: BTW, this would be somewhat easier to read if your `map` were a `collections.defaultdict(lambda: (0,0))` -- that way you could take the conditional logic to handle the untracked case out of your loop.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy CR want code the OP wrote, not code they want explaining to them

Comment: (Using the variable name `map` is also unfortunate, inasmuch as that conflicts with a built-in function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` values are each tuples corresponding with the number of items seen and the total of all values seen for the same item.

Dividing the two does indeed return the average (though since they're integers, that result is rounded -- consider casting one or both to floating-point if you want a floating-point result rather than an integer result).

Comment: so it outputs the average value for all the scores it received from the two reviewers? should I move the post to CR? :/

Comment: No, don't move it to CR -- @jonrsharpe is right that code you didn't write yourself isn't welcome there. And it's the average, *but rounded to a floating-point value* unless using Python 3.

Comment: err, "rounded to an integer value" unless using Python 3, rather.